# facing issue in changing the name of tensor in tensorboard projector?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tensorflow-hub

I am facing issue while changing the name of tensorboard projector, the name of tensor is defined  here in the code but

```
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding = config.embeddings.add()

embedding.tensor_name = "embedding/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE" # this is the name here.
embedding.metadata_path = 'metadata.tsv'
```

i think the value is static and no other name can be written.

Tried defining some other name but data was not present in the projector.